# Getting the option text for selected option in select list angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My select list data looks like this

```
{
  123: 'abc',
  234: 'bcd',
  .
  .
}
```

I am using ng-options in template to render this like

```
<select ng-model="myOption" ng-option="key as value for (key, value) in data"></select>
```

Now I want to get the option text for selected option in js controller

Is it possible?

PS- I can't change the data structure of data for select list, 
so make it a object of objects as shown below is out of question

```
{
 {
   name: 'abc',
   value: 123
 },
 {
   name: 'bcd',
   value: 234
 }
}
```

EDIT: I still want to be able to access the selected key i.e. 123 or 234

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `ng-change` and implement a function to get the value by key

```
<div>
    <select ng-model="myOption" ng-options="key as value for (key, value) in data" ng-change="getVal(myOption)"></select>

    {{selectVal}}
</div>

$scope.getVal = function(val){
    $scope.selectVal = $scope.data[val]
}
```

not that its `ng-options` with `s`

demo

```js
angular.module("app",[])
.controller("ctrl",function($scope){
$scope.data = {
  123: 'abc',
  234: 'bcd', 
}
$scope.getVal = function(val){
    $scope.selectVal = $scope.data[val]
}
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
 <select ng-model="myOption" ng-options="key as value for (key, value) in data" ng-change="getVal(myOption)"></select>
{{selectVal}}
</div>
```

Comment: @sachilaranawaka I dont want to lose the ability to access the value of selected option i.e. 123 or 234, I have edited the question

Comment: @madhur then you can use `ng-change` for that. check the demo again